# how to return svelte store as promise instead of an object with subscribe

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I have a svelte store like so taken from [this example](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions):

**store.ts**

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const count = writable(0);
```

**test.svelte**

```js
function increment() {
    count.update(n => n + 1);
}
```

I can get the value like so:

**app.svelte**

```js
const unsubscribe = count.subscribe(value => {
    count_value = value;
});
```

But is it possible to just get the value **just once** using an await / Promise instead of an observable-like object with subscribe?

Example:

```js
const count-value = await count.toPromise();
```

Obviously `toPromise` does not exists on a **Writable** object, but I thought maybe through **rxjs**, **internal svelte**, or **wonka** there might be an option or some kind of work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any promise API with Svelte stores. If you want to get the value just once, you can use [get](https://svelte.dev/docs#get).

```js
import { get } from 'svelte/store';

const countValue = get(count);
```

Though this is not recommended in hot code paths. From the docs:

> This works by creating a subscription, reading the value, then unsubscribing. It's therefore not recommended in hot code paths.

Comment: While not a promise, it solves the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also write:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const count = writable(0);

function increment() {
    $count += 1;
    console.log($count);
};

increment();
```

Or share a counter with setContext and getContext

**counter.svelte:**

```
  import { setContext } from 'svelte';

  let count = 10;
  setContext('counter', {
    get count() {return count},
    increment: () => {count += 1},
    getCount: async () => {return await count} 
  });
```

**increment.svelte:**

```
import { setContext } from 'svelte';

const counter = getContext('counter');
counter.increment();
```

**getters.svelte:**

```
import { getContext } from 'svelte';

const counter = getContext('counter');
console.log(counter.count);
counter.getCount().then((c) => console.log(c));
```